# There may be a mistaken on official document

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

the document url is https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/document/

about the getSubItemsWithProperties function, this type of first argument may by object instead of string.

[image: screenshot of document page]

Comment: How you considered contacting the authors of the document?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I'm reviewing this with my documentation team!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again for your feedback, my team made the changes on the documentation and it should be live on our next publish.